# Autosys command job starting earlier than given start_time

Tags: autosys

I am new to AutoSys, and am facing a strange error. I have a box job with a few command jobs inside. The box is scheduled at 5:00 am, and the command jobs have different "start_times". A few of these are scheduled to start at 10:30 pm.

The problem is all these 10:30 pm jobs kick off as soon as the box job starts (at 5:00 am) whereas the other jobs start at their respective time.

What is the error here ?

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the autosys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your box was not running at 10:30PM the previous night, then those jobs will start immediately when the box begins running at 5:00AM the next morning.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Erick. I'm thinking here that your 10:30 jobs are not included in the success condition of your main box. Thus, your main box already succeeded before 10:30 that's why your jobs with 10:30 schedule inside your box are not being triggered; and it will be triggered simultaneously the next day with your main box. You can check your the success/failure condition of your box.